# Php Date subtract Date and print them custom format

Tags: php, date, subtraction

I have a db that I store update date as `date("d-m-Y")` I would like to subtrack another date from this date.

like 01-10-2015 - 04-07-2012

I would like to print result as **ex 3 years 3 mounths and 3 days ago**.

How can I do that?

Comment: what code you tried, show here first..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is Your need ,

```
<?php
   $date1 = new DateTime('04-07-2012'); // old date
   $date2 = new DateTime('01-10-2015'); // new date
   $interval = $date1->diff($date2); // date differ function
   echo $interval->format("%y years  %m months  %d days ago"); // formatting date 
?>
```

> **OUTPUT:  3 years 2 months 27 days ago**

You can also refer :  [Date Time Difference](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php)

Comment: This code works with 04-07-2012 - 01-10-2015 both 2012-07-04 - 2015-10-01 how does it undestand which one is month and which one is day?

Comment: php DateTime class constructor accept parameter in both case like "d-m-Y" or " Y-m-d " to parse it in time string. So it can be handled by the class. Go through with doc: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php for better understanding

Answer (score 0):

get the days difference using following code :

```
$date1=date_create("2013-03-15");
$date2=date_create("2013-12-12");
$diff=date_diff($date1,$date2);
echo $diff->format("%y years, %m months, %d days ago");
// will print "0 years, 8 months, 27 days ago"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$datetime1 = date_create('2009-10-11');
$datetime2 = date_create('2009-10-13');
$interval = date_diff($datetime1, $datetime2);
echo $interval->format('%R%a days');
?>
```

You can reffer The time format in http://php.net/manual